# take screenshot for label using for loop

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to take screenshot for each time random create string.

I mad a gui program using python and pyqt5. I have a label which I insert an image into it and I have two other labels which set to set text randomly using random and string module.
so, I want to take screenshot for that label which ( lets consider that) has an image and two label for every time random string set on label.

```
def createCards(self):
    cardsNum = int(self.lineEdit_23.text())
    S = 5
    
    while cardsNum != 0:
        self.label_8.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label_9.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        
        self.label_8.setText(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k = S)))
        self.label_9.setText(''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k = S)))
        

        pics_path = 'pics/%s.jpg'%(str(pics))

        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
        screenshot = screen.grabWindow( self.label_7.winId())
        screenshot.save(pics_path, 'jpg')
        cardsNum -= 1
```

Comment: your code was really useful, but one thing... only save one screenshot image even if the self.cardsNum is largrer than one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the same logic using signals, for example through a QTimer.

```
from functools import cached_property
```

```
@cached_property
def timer(self):
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.setInterval(100)
    timer.timeout.connect(self.take_screenshot)
    return timer


def createCards(self):
    self.cardsNum = int(self.lineEdit_23.text())
    self.timer.start()


def take_screenshot(self):
    S = 5

    if self.cardsNum == 0:
        self.timer.stop()
    else:
        self.label_8.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label_9.setFrameShape(QFrame.NoFrame)

        self.label_8.setText(
            "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=S))
        )
        self.label_9.setText(
            "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=S))
        )

        pics_path = "pics/%s.jpg" % (str(pics))

        screen = QtWidgets.QApplication.primaryScreen()
        screenshot = screen.grabWindow(self.label_7.winId())
        screenshot.save(pics_path, "jpg")
        self.cardsNum -= 1
```

Comment: thank you very much, but can you tell me why it would repeat the first image and drop the last one?